# Unit testing validator constraints with symfony2.3

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony-validator

I would like to make a test unit using constraint but I have this error when running my test

This are my different classes and the obtaining error after running phpunit

```html
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Age18 extends Constraint
{
 public $message = 'Vous devez avoir 18 ans.';

}


use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class Age18Validator extends ConstraintValidator
{
 public function validate($dateNaissance, Constraint $constraint)
 {
  if ($dateNaissance > new \DateTime("18 years ago"))
  {
   $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
  }
 }
}


use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class Age18ValidatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
 private $constraint;

 public function setUp()
 {
  $this->constraint = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint');
 }

 public function testValidate()
 {
  /*ConstraintValidator*/
  $validator = new Age18Validator();
  $context = $this
     ->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext')
     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
     ->getMock('Age18Validator', array('validate'));

  $context->expects($this->once())
    ->method('addViolation')
    ->with('Vous devez avoir 18 ans.');
  $validator->initialize($context);
  $validator->validate('10/10/2000', $this->constraint);
 }

 public function tearDown()
 {
  $this->constraint = null;
 }
}
```

```html
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:addViolation> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Please could you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the type of your element: in the validator class you use the comparator between two DateTime object but in the test you pass a string to the validator.

This is my test class:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\Form;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints\Age18;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints\Age18Validator;

class Age18ValidatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $constraint;
    private $context;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->constraint = new Age18();
        $this->context = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    }

    public function testValidate()
    {


        /*ConstraintValidator*/
        $validator = new Age18Validator();
        $validator->initialize( $this->context);

        $this->context->expects($this->once())
            ->method('addViolation')
            ->with($this->constraint->message,array());
        $validator->validate(\Datetime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y","10/10/2000"), $this->constraint);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->constraint = null;
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Good look, It was the type of the element. Now It walk very fine. Thanks a lot